# How do I convert SRM to L*a*b* using E-308 as an algorithm?

Tags: javascript, colors

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to apply ASTM E-308 to SRM measurements for beer. The problem domain in which I am working requires that we have a decent conversion from SRM to RGB (or sRGB) via conversion to L*a*b* first. It seems that every site I use to create a beer recipe has their own conversion from SRM to RGB, which makes sense, given that it's a sticky problem. That said, I'm looking to write an open source js library that will handle the problem.

Basically, I'm using the algorithm as described here: https://www.homebrewtalk.com/forum/threads/on-the-calculation-of-srm-rgb-values-in-the-srgb-color-space.413581/#post-5232912

Which I believe is a simplification of the E-308 algorithm. Where I'm having difficulty is that the spreadsheet mentioned in that post (http://wetnewf.org/pdfs/Brewing_articles/MOAWorkbook.xls) doesn't make a ton of sense to me. The post says to choose a XYZ vector based on the observer angle from the spreadsheet. If I choose a 10 degree observer angle, then I would expect that the XYZ vector should be: (82.82, 3.48, 61.86). Is this correct?

Now, choosing an illuminant spectrum is also somewhat confusing. If I want illuminant C (which I believe to be 6774K), what values do I pull from that spreadsheet to add as components for the spectrum? Moreover, how do I calculate these components?

I have some limited background in color theory, but what I'd really like is to be able to have some set of input criteria, say, observer angle and illuminant color temperature, along with the SRM value, and compute an L*a*b* value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question that does warrant an answer that is probably not suitable for Stack Overflow format.

ASTM E308 by itself is a 50 pages complex standard whose main body is about conversion from spectral distribution to CIE XYZ tristimulus values. It also touches conversion to CIE Lab and CIE Luv.

The spreadsheet you linked does not fully implement ASTM E308 and *conveniently* use the integration method for 5 nm measurement intervals without a table of tristimulus weighting factors which you technically need if the spectral data is bandpass corrected. It is fine for practical purposes but if precision is required it is important to know that ASTM E308 is very strict.

The spreadsheet is quite complex because it seems to use the [Augmented SRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Reference_Method#Augmented_SRM)
computation with the eigen-vectors for the hundred or so of beers.

Assuming that you want to use the [ASBC method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Reference_Method#Tristimulus_color), the process should be as follows:

- Compute the beer transmission spectral distribution for given SRM and path length using the following equation:

[image]

- Convert the spectral distribution to CIE XYZ tristimulus values using the integration method for the CIE 1964 10 Degree Standard Observer and Illuminant C
- Convert the CIE XYZ tristimulus values to CIE Lab
- To go further, convert them also to sRGB
- Drink beer :)

If you don't mind reading Python, I made a [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1v26EGSM9CjgIcpO6u7qXgmjrRKvvyNHW) that uses [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) and computes beer colour for a grid of SRM and path lengths:

```python
import colour
import colour.plotting
import numpy as np

colour.utilities.describe_environment()

colour.plotting.colour_style()

ASBC_SHAPE = colour.SpectralShape(380, 780, 5)

OBSERVER = colour.CMFS['CIE 1964 10 Degree Standard Observer']
ILLUMINANT = colour.ILLUMINANTS_SDS['C']
ILLUMINANT_XY = colour.ILLUMINANTS['CIE 1931 2 Degree Standard Observer']['C']


def beer_transmission_sd(SRM, path=1, shape=ASBC_SHAPE):
    e = np.exp(1)
    wl = shape.range()
    values = np.exp(
        -(SRM / 12.7) * (0.018747 * e**(-(wl - 430) / 13.374) + 0.98226 * e**
                        (-(wl - 430) / 80.514)) * path)

    return colour.SpectralDistribution(
        values, wl, name='Beer - SRM {0} - Path {1}'.format(SRM, path))


PATHS = np.linspace(10, 1, 10)
SRM = np.linspace(1, 50, 50)
XYZ = []

for i in PATHS:
    for j in SRM:
        XYZ.append(
            colour.sd_to_XYZ(
                beer_transmission_sd(i, j),
                cmfs=OBSERVER,
                illuminant=ILLUMINANT) / 100.0)

# The Lab values for CIE Illuminant C are computed here:
Lab = colour.XYZ_to_Lab(XYZ, ILLUMINANT_XY)

# But we will be going further :)
RGB = colour.XYZ_to_sRGB(XYZ, illuminant=ILLUMINANT_XY)

figure, axes = colour.plotting.plot_multi_colour_swatches(
    [colour.plotting.ColourSwatch(RGB=np.clip(i, 0, 1)) for i in RGB],
    columns=len(SRM),
    **{
        'standalone': False,
        'x_label': 'SRM',
        'y_label': 'Path (cm)',
        'xtick.bottom': True,
        'ytick.left': True,
    })

# Ugly ticks massaging that will not be needed in future versions.
axes.set_xticks(SRM)
axes.set_yticks(-PATHS + 2)
axes.set_yticklabels(reversed(PATHS))

colour.plotting.render(standalone=True);
```

[image: Beer Colour]

Note that it should be straightforward to have Colour running in a container in the backend via Flask and call it from Javascript. We have an [advanced 3D visualiser](https://github.com/colour-science/colour-analysis-three.js) that can be helpful should you want to go down that road.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! One additional question I have: when you say "Compute the beer transmission spectral distribution for given SRM and path length using the following equation", does that mean that you'd sample a set of wavelengths (e.g. 280nm, 285nm, etc...) and plug these in to that equation for lambda to get a set of values representing a discrete form of the spectral distribution?

Comment: Yes! I should have commented the code better in that respect, basically `wl = shape.range()` generates all the wavelengths according to `ASBC_SHAPE`. The code uses Numpy under the hood, most of it is vectorised so no loops.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really trying to understand this, rather than just blindly copy the code given. Another question: Once you've created a `SpectralDistribution`, for each of the lambda values, the ASTM E-308-15 algorithm will convert each wavelength to a tuple of CIE (X, Y, Z) values, correct? (In other words, the output of the `sd_to_xyz` function should be an array of 3-tuples, yes?

Comment: Absolutely correct! The definition/code of interest for that particular conversion is here: https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/2ca84a2ce6c92ea1ea9e54f1b75e501e80970058/colour/colorimetry/tristimulus.py#L403